# Total_ordering and class inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, functools

From what I understand, the `total_ordering` decorator from `functools` is not expected to work nicely with classes inherited from an ordered class: it doesn't try to define the comparison functions because they are already defined.

See this example:

```
from functools import total_ordering
from collections import namedtuple

Test = namedtuple('Test',['a','b'])

@total_ordering
class TestOrd(Test):
    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self.b < other.b or self.b == other.b and self.a < other.a

x = TestOrd(a=1,b=2)
y = TestOrd(a=2,b=1)
print(x < y)   # Expected: False
print(x <= y)  #           False
print(x > y)   #           True
print(x >= y)  #           True
print(y < x)   #           True
print(y <= x)  #           True
print(y > x)   #           False
print(y >= x)  #           False
```

Of all the tests, only the ones involving the `<` operator give the expected result.

I can get the `>` ones to work as well by adding `__gt__ = lambda *_ : NotImplemented` to the class definition.
On the other hand, if I add similar definitions for `__le__` or `__ge__`, the corresponding tests fail with (for `__le__`):

```
TypeError: unorderable types: TestOrd() <= TestOrd()
```

which leads me to believe that this is not the proper way to address the problem.

Hence the question: **is there a proper way to reorder a class with total_ordering?**

(Yes, I know that doing `total_ordering`'s job by hand is trivial, and I know that for this example, defining an unordered `namedtuple` is trivial too.)

Comment: *"is there a proper way to reorder a class with total_ordering?"* - no, as you point out it will only replace the methods that aren't already defined, so the inheriting class must override all of them explicitly to reorder.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Maybe a way to mark some method as undefined? After all, it can be done for `>` for example...

Comment: I don't think you understand what that does; it doesn't affect `total_ordering` (which is looking for *existence*, not *implementation*). If you remove the decorator, the behaviour won't change. I suppose you could make a new ordering decorator that looks only at methods defined directly on that specific class (check in `__dict__` rather than `dir`).

Comment: Oh, I see, the interpreter does fall back on `__lt__` if `__gt__` is not implemented, regardless of `total_ordering`. Thanks, indeed I was misinterpreting that behavior.

Comment: For the second part of your comment, it could be an idea. Or maybe even simply define a weaker decorator which would require that we tell it what operators it can trust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your example, you could solve the problem by introducing an additional base class that does not directly inherit from `Test`:

```
Test = namedtuple('Test',['a','b'])

@total_ordering
class TestOrdBase:
    def __lt__(self ,other):
        return self.b < other.b or self.b == other.b and self.a < other.a

class TestOrd(TestOrdBase, Test):
    pass
```

The order of the base classes for `TestOrd` is important, `TestOrdBase` must come before `Test`.

Comment: Aha, thanks! If can even be done with a more generic `OrdBase` delegating the comparison to a function defined by `TestOrd` later (I guess that the preference will depend on how many such classes we will need to define and how much more goes into the subclass). Duck-typing at its best!

Comment: It's usual to refer to a class like that as a "mix-in", although in this case it's quite closely tied to the implementation of the class you're mixing it into.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the implementation of `total_ordering`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/functools.py#l192), we can see the problem:

```
roots = [op for op in _convert if getattr(cls, op, None) is not getattr(object, op, None)]
```

This carefully checks that the versions defined on `cls` aren't those inherited from `object`, but any other inherited methods will be included (i.e. not replaced). The minimal tweak is to define your own copy (I've called it `total_reordering`) that instead uses:

```
roots = set(cls.__dict__) & set(_convert)
```

(based on the [previous implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/functools.py#l53)). This looks at only the methods directly defined on the class, causing the decorator to override the inherited versions. This gives the results that you expected to begin with:

```
False
False
True
True
True
True
False
False
```

---

Note that you've misunderstood what defining:

```
 __gt__ = lambda *_ : NotImplemented
```

does; it doesn't change what the decorator's doing (which is nothing, in this case), it's just overriding the inherited version and causing `>` to get delegated to the other methods at runtime.